# What design pattern facilitates a test sequencer?

Tags: .net, design-patterns

I've been tasked with porting the control software for a custom test machine from LabView (too slow and inflexible) to .net.   The control software accepts a high level test plan, determines how to implement it by building a sequence of actions, then performing the sequence.

For illustration, a simple scenario would be a to implement the test plan, "Test each device on wafer at 25C and 85C, stimulating each device with 10, 35, 50ma, recording signal strength for each device, spectra for 10% of all devices."

My thoughts on design are in the direction of a 'sequencer', code which assembles and maintains a series of actions (move stages, command instrumentation, etc) which are handed off to objects which perform one or more actions.  In this way I hope to separate 'what' to do from the 'how' of doing it.

I would appreciate thoughts on design pattern(s) which would help me organize this application.

Comment: Have you actually got working code doing any of the things you need to do yet? I normally find a round of prototyping to be the first stage before I worry about fitting to any design patterns.

Comment: No code yet, looking to architect and design over the next couple of weeks.

Comment: Not a design pattern per se, but it sounds as you want to build some sort of test cases? Maybe you could look into using some of the BDD frameworks for the given/then/when steps i.e. StoryQ if you'll write C# code directly, or SpecFlow if they will be written by someone using the tool. Even if you don't end using those, they could prove useful to have an idea on how to achieve your goal